# How can I find the “friendly name” of the operating system from the shell / Terminal / bash?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

[image: About this Mac with the word 'Mojave' circled]

I know that I can use `sw_ver` to find *this* information:

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14
BuildVersion:   18A353d
```

…and I know I can find other things like `uname` can give me some types of information about the OS, and `system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType` can give me additional information, but I want to find the “friendly” name, such as “Mojave” in the image shown above.

How can I find the “friendly” name, using the shell / Terminal / bash / etc ?

So far my Google fu has failed to turn up any solutions. All the results seem to come back to those commands I mentioned above, but none of those give me the right information.

It has to be in there somewhere… how can I find it?

Comment: Pointing out that the correct answer would just be retrieve the number via whatever method, and have your own lookup table for the name.

Comment: I'm filing a radar against `sw_ver` since this marketing name clearly should be emitted from that command. I've done a lot of spelunking looking for this and I'm guessing you'll need a very oblique way to get this from installed updates with the name.

Comment: Why?  It's easily determinable, the names are all known and all you have to do is index into a list.  I provide a (bad) Applescript below.

Answer (score 9):

#### Offline Method

This command should find what you're looking for:

```
awk '/SOFTWARE LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR macOS/' '/System/Library/CoreServices/Setup Assistant.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/OSXSoftwareLicense.rtf' | awk -F 'macOS ' '{print $NF}' | awk '{print substr($0, 0, length($0)-1)}'
```

It's based off the answer found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234104/get-osx-codename-from-command-line).  It's tested to work in High Sierra and should work in Mojave.

#### Online Method

You can also do this online (which is actually what populates "About this Mac" dialog shown in the question):

```
curl -s https://support-sp.apple.com/sp/product?edid=$( sw_vers -productVersion ) | xmllint --format -xpath "//root/configCode/text()" -
```

This command will query Apple's server with your product version and will extract the OS name from the XML response.  To see the full XML response, simply omit the `--xpath "//root/configCode/text()"` option:

```
curl -s https://support-sp.apple.com/sp/product?edid=$( sw_vers -productVersion ) | xmllint --format  -
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <name>CPU Name</name>
   <configCode>macOS High Sierra</configCode>
   <locale>en_US</locale>
</root>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me “High Sierra” as output on my Mojave machine. The word 'Mojave' doesn't appear in the file.

Comment: also, from that same link, someone suggested this, which also does not work (returns nothing):

`VER="$(sw_vers -productVersion)"; curl -s "http://support-sp.apple.com/sp/product?edid=$VER"`

Comment: It's probably because they haven't updated the file for Mojave, yet.  The online service seems to no longer work as I cannot get it to respond to any query.  That one will take more digging

Comment: I was able to get the second one functioning.  You need `https` as Apple will ignore non-ssl connections.  I also added the `xmllint` filter to extract the data you're looking for.

Comment: I don't have a pre-Sierra machine to check, but wouldn't the "offline" method above fail, pre-Sierra?  It didn't call itself "macOS" before that.  I'm not a fan of solutions where the machine is required to have an Internet connection.

Comment: @MarcWilson -  This answer was written with the new macOS and above in mind.  If you want El Capitan and earlier, change it to "OS X"

Comment: I'm getting a '0900' error:
    `$ curl -s https://support-sp.apple.com/sp/product?edid=$( sw_vers -productVersion )`
returns
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><root><error>0900</error><locale>en_US</locale></root>`
on 10.13.6 (and any other valueI use there)

Comment: @johnnyB - I just tested it and it works fine on my end.  Are you using a Hackintosh, perhaps?

Comment: so 10.13.6 does not work! `$ curl -s "https://support-sp.apple.com/sp/product?edid=10.13.6"` Fails but `curl -s "https://support-sp.apple.com/sp/product?edid=10.12.6"` works!!!

Comment: @Allan the online method is not consistent.  See my new questions at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341551/online-way-to-get-macos-friendly-name

Answer (score 2):

Well, I finally gave up looking for a solution -- maybe we'll find one after Mojave hits its final release, but it obviously won't be something that it easily used on older versions of Mac OS X / OS X / macOS.

So I made an alternative to [Marc Wilson’s idea](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/333468/9226) (above) and created a shell script which can either output a full list of *all* of the version numbers and their “friendly names” or will allow you to search for a specific name, for example, if you just want to know which version was called “Yosemite”.

You can find my script here:
https://github.com/tjluoma/macosxnames/blob/master/macosxnames.sh

I’ll leave the question open in case we do find a solution that doesn’t require an external script.

### Update (over a year later)

Apple now maintains a web page with all of the names and corresponding numbers: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201260

You can get the list using this:

```
(echo "<table>" ; curl -sfLS "https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201260" \
| tidy --tidy-mark no --char-encoding utf8 --wrap 0 --show-errors 0 --show-warnings no --clean yes --force-output yes --output-xhtml yes --quiet yes \
| sed -e '1,/<table/d; /<\/table>/,$d' -e 's#<br />##g' ; echo "</table>" ) \
| lynx -dump -nomargins -width='10000' -assume_charset=UTF-8 -pseudo_inlines -stdin -nonumbers -nolist
```

Will give this output:

```
        macOS         Latest version
macOS Monterey        12.4
macOS Big Sur         11.6.7
macOS Catalina        10.15.2
macOS Mojave          10.14.6
macOS High Sierra     10.13.6
macOS Sierra          10.12.6
OS X El Capitan       10.11.6
OS X Yosemite         10.10.5
OS X Mavericks        10.9.5
OS X Mountain Lion    10.8.5
OS X Lion             10.7.5
Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8
Mac OS X Leopard      10.5.8
Mac OS X Tiger        10.4.11
Mac OS X Panther      10.3.9
Mac OS X Jaguar       10.2.8
Mac OS X Puma         10.1.5
Mac OS X Cheetah      10.0.4
```

Then again, Apple isn’t great about keeping documentation online, so it may be gone in a year or two.

Comment: Thank you for this list.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72722226/1896134  I updated this and created a python script off of this to dynamically lookup and compare versions.  I can now get the OS Name in python by parsing the `sw_vers` into vars and comparing to the list.  Github: https://github.com/JayRizzo/JayRizzoTools/blob/master/pyMacOsName.py

Comment: Looks like the page layout has just changed.  You need to also remove paragraph marks from within the table.  Probably adding `-e 's#</\?p[^>]*>##g'` will do (tested on GNU sed from Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

```
set _delim to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
set os_version to the second item of (the text items of (do shell script "sw_vers -productVersion"))
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to _delim

set osList to { "Puma", "Cheetah", "Jaguar", "Panther", "Tiger", "Leopard", "Snow Leopard",¬
                "Lion", "Mountain Lion", "Mavericks", "Yosemite", "El Capitan", "Sierra", "High Sierra"}

return item (os_version+1) of osList
```

That's an example.

Comment: The script indeed solve the purpose, but isn't scalable. It will have to be updated with each major release of macOS. The intent seems to be figuring out a mechanism build into macOS (or using the information built into OS) which can reveal the marketing name of the release.

Comment: @NimeshNeema it is however the only solution that gives the correct answer

Comment: As long as you're shelling out, you can use the following to replace the first 4 lines of your script: `set os_version to (do shell script "sw_vers -productVersion | awk -F. '{print $2}'")`

Comment: Really, if I were going to do that, I'd do the whole thing in awk. :)  I like awk.