# Apple's online version function support-sp.apple.com/sp/product?edid= does not work for all macOS versions

Tags: terminal, mac, bash

I would like to get the Apple marketing name, the code name, for a given version of macOS (e.g. 10.12 is macOS Sierra) from Apple's online service at `support-sp.apple.com/sp/product?edid=`.

This is possible for some versions using the http request:

```
curl https://support-sp.apple.com/sp/product?edid=10.12.0
```

However, I cannot get the URL to give a consistent answer to `https://support-sp.apple.com/sp/product?edid=<ver>`.

I was trying to confirm my 10.13.6 version and kept getting errors. I tried 10.14.0 and it did not work. Trying 10.12.6 works, so I made a loop to try all versions:

```
$ for i in {6..14} ; do echo "10.${i}.0:" $(curl -s "https://support-sp.apple.com/sp/product?edid=10.${i}.0" | xmllint --format -xpath "//root/configCode/text()" - 2>/dev/null) ; done
```

returns:

`10.6.0: Mac OS X 10.6
10.7.0: OS X Lion
10.8.0: OS X Mountain Lion
10.9.0: OS X Mavericks
10.10.0:
10.11.0: OS X El Capitan
10.12.0: macOS Sierra
10.13.0:
10.14.0:`

If this isn't possible, is there a better place to ensure that when run from a bash shell on **most** macOS systems I can get the friendly name? At least the last 6 or so versions (I'm not sure how many pre-Lion versions there are out there in the wild).

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of How can I find the “friendly name” of the operating system from the shell / Terminal / bash? because (as you can see my comment there) the "optional" solution does NOT work. I commented but there is NOT enough room to explain so I opened up this new question.

Comment: the `support-sp.apple.com` is given as an answer in: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/333452/how-can-i-find-the-friendly-name-of-the-operating-system-from-the-shell-term/ , https://superuser.com/questions/797687/can-i-get-the-osxs-animal-name-from-the-terminal-instead-of-just-the-version , and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/333452/how-can-i-find-the-friendly-name-of-the-operating-system-from-the-shell-term.  none mention that 10.13.6 and 10.14.0 do not work (the latest versions of the OS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct -  new macOS versions are not working from that lookup.

I get error 9 now from that curl command for strings 11 and higher (and confirm your lack of results for High Sierra and later versions of 10)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><root><error>0009</error><locale></locale></root>%
```

You will probably want to define these strings in your script and/or [look them up another offline manner](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/334337/5472) or run your own web API if you need that for some reason.